# libgtk-3.so.0 not found when trying to run mongodb-compass from RedHAt Linux

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I tried installing the latest version of Mongo compass by running the RPM in the red hat instance:

sudo yum install mongodb-compass-1.17.0.x86_64.rpm

When I try to run the mongodb-compass, I am getting the below error:
[ec2-user@ip-10-93-230-148 ~]$ mongodb-compass
mongodb-compass: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Can anyone please advise on how to resolve this issue?

Thanks
DJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to run compass in Redhat instance by installing gtk3-devel